# How do we obtain the relativistic dispersion relation from wave function of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics

If we have a plane wave, $$\psi(t,\textbf{r})=Ae^{i(\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}-\omega t)}$$ we can apply the QM energy operator ($\hat{\mathcal{E}}=i\hbar\partial_{t}$) to the wave function, we get:$$\hat{\mathcal{E}}\psi(t,\textbf{r})=\hbar \omega\psi(t,\textbf{r})$$Similarly, applying the momentum operator ($\hat{\mathcal{P}}=-i\hbar\nabla$) to the plane wave, we have $$\hat{\mathcal{P}}\psi(t,\textbf{r})=\hbar\textbf{k}\psi(t,\textbf{r})$$ The phase velocity of the plane wave should be $$v=\frac{\omega}{k}$$ So if $E=\hbar \omega$ and $p=\hbar k$, $E=\hbar vk=v p$, then if the particle has velocity that is the speed of light, $E^{2}=c^{2}p^{2}$, as you would expect. However i can't see the equivalence between:
$$E^{2}=v^{2}p^{2}$$ and
$$E^{2}=m^2c^{4}+p^{2}c^{2}$$ Is there a way to demonstrate this equivalence? or is there no equivalence? Even more confusingly, by boosting a massive particle at rest in 1+1D, 4-momentum which is initially $$P= \begin{bmatrix}
mc^{2} \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Transforms under a Lorentz boost as
$$\Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu} P^{\mu}=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma && \beta\gamma\\
\beta\gamma && \gamma \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
mc^{2} \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma mc^{2} \\
\beta\gamma mc^{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus, $$p=\beta E$$ which is seemingly the oppsite of what I derived previously.

Comment: The second energy-equation becomes equivalent to the first one for massless particles (e.g. photons).

Comment: yes, i understand that much, however surely there should be some equivalence between the two equations for massive particles? I.e, since we can describe massive particles propagating in a vacuum as a plane wave, then the 1st derived equation should hold, and there should be some correspondance between the two

Comment: QM is non-relativistic, so you cannot expect it to give you the relativistic expression for $E^2$. The relevant "energy operator" for relativistic fermions is found in the Dirac equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Schrödinger equation for the free non-relativistic particle, where
$$
H= \frac{p^2}{2 m} 
$$
therefore, the dispersion relation that you obtain can only be consistent with
$$
E= \hbar \omega = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m} 
$$
This is the usual kinetic energy of a non-relativistic particle, nothing more to say: it is the non-relativistic limit of the usual relativistic dispersion relation, in the sense that
$$
E=\sqrt{m^2c^{4}+p^{2}c^{2}} \approx \frac{p^2}{2 m}  + m c^2 \, 
\qquad (\text{for } \quad p\ll c\, m)
$$

Comment: I see, how come this works for massless particles then, since these are clearly relativistic?

Comment: for massless particles, this theory is NOT the correct one (as you say, massless particles are relativistic, and this is NON-relativistic Quantum mechanics). You have to study Quantum Field Theory (i.e. special relativity+quantum mechanics) if you want to understand massless particles... this is a rather different and more advanced  theory.

Comment: I've read up more on this since your response now, thanks